# Discord.js error = "message is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    let userInfMent = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]))
    message.channel.send(userInfo(userInfMent));
    }

function userInfo(user) {
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    let userInfMent = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]))
    var userCreated = userInfMent.createdAt.toString().split(' ');
    var lastMsg = userInfMent.lastMessage.createdAt.toString().split(' ')

    const userInfoEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .addField('Никнейм: ', userInfMent.username)
    .addField('Тег: ', userInfMent.tag)
    .addField('ID: ', userInfMent.id)
    .addField('Аккаунт был создан: ', userCreated[1] + ', ' + userCreated[2] + ', ' + userCreated[3])
    .addField('Последнее сообщение: ', userInfMent.lastMessage + ' в ' + lastMsg[1] + ', ' + lastMsg[2] + ', ' + lastMsg[3] + ', ' + lastMsg[4])
    .addField('Статус: ', userInfMent.presence.status)
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setThumbnail(userInfMent.avatarURL);

    return userInfoEmbed
}
```

**Hi. I'm a Node.js beginner.**

When i start the command, in console i see the error:

> (node:6312) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: message
>   is not defined
>       at userInfo (C:\Users\deris\Desktop\Проекты\Node.js\discord.js\JSBot-master\commands\userinfo.js:10:23)
>       at Object.exports.run (C:\Users\deris\Desktop\Проекты\Node.js\discord.js\JSBot-master\commands\userinfo.js:5:26)

Comment: It could be a encoding error from cyrillic to "normal" chars or it could also be a code error. So could you thest the code with "normal" chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message` is only defined in the message event itself. So you can simply pass the `message` object as a parameter into your function.

```js
// new function 
function userInfo(user, message) {
    //code here
}
```

Just remember that you'll have to add the additional parameter when you call the function.

```js
message.channel.send(userInfo(userInfMent, message));
```

Answer (score 0):

Message is not defined because you did not put the code in a [Message Event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message).

Answer (score 0):

I just been learning and found this one out.

Message.channel.send will not work inside a function. The function will read it as a variable. And since message hasn't been defined we draw the error.

outside the function the command will again work fine. I'm not sure if it's an error with the current builds or intentional. But there is your fix

Comment: Use typeof Message.channel.send to verify if send is actually a function or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your using `message.guild.member` inside of the function and didn't define `member` which is causing the problem. Consider placing the function inside of the export